# How to fix "warning: could not open directory" after "git add ." command on Mac OS X Maverick

Tags: r, git

I'm new to R and RStudio and am currently taking online classes to learn more about data science. In one of my lectures, I'm being asked to create a project in RStudio prior to creating a repository in github and linking the project with git. In order to make a pre-existing project interact with git, the instructions in my lecture are telling me to navigate to the directory containing my project file by using the "cd" command followed by the location of the file and file name. My project file is currently located on my desktop so I typed in "cd ~ /Desktop/temporary_no_version_control" however, the directory doesn't seem to change and remains set on the original location of the file which was in Users/savannahkeiffer. Just so I could complete the assignment, I re-located the file to my user file and tried to follow the rest of the instructions which told me to type "git init" followed by "git add ." which is where I run into the "warning: could not open directory" warning.

I have a macbook which runs on OS X Maverick. I went into my system preferences > security and privacy and selected Full Disk Access where I manually allowed terminal to have access to all the files on my laptop. However, after closing and re-opening RStudio and attempting the commands again, I got the same error.

This is what I entered when I tried to change the directory

```
Savannahs-MacBook-Air-2:~ savannahkeiffer$ cd ~ 
/Desktop/temporary_no_version_control

Savannahs-MacBook-Air-2:~ savannahkeiffer$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in 
/Users/savannahkeiffer/.git/
```

And what I got when I changed the location of the project on my laptop in order to complete the assignment (after already giving access to terminal)

```
Savannahs-MacBook-Air-2:~ savannahkeiffer$ cd ~ 
/Users/savannahkeiffer/first project/temporary_no_version_control

Savannahs-MacBook-Air-2:~ savannahkeiffer$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in 
/Users/savannahkeiffer/.git/

Savannahs-MacBook-Air-2:~ savannahkeiffer$ git add .

warning: could not open directory 'Pictures/Photos 
Library.photoslibrary/': Operation not permitted

warning: could not open directory 'Library/Application 
Support/MobileSync/': Operation not permitted

warning: could not open directory 'Library/Application 
Support/CallHistoryTransactions/': Operation not permitted

warning: could not open directory 'Library/Application 
Support/com.apple.TCC/': Operation not permitted

warning: could not open directory 'Library/Application 
Support/AddressBook/': Operation not permitted
```

And so on.. Is this a directory problem or a "git add ." command problem?

Comment: Do not run `git init .` on your home. Use some other directory (even inside your home.... like **~/blahblah**).

Comment: What error do you get when you run cd to the original location of the project? Can you put the output over here so that we can see what's going on?

Comment: "Operation not permitted" suggests that you are getting `EPERM` errors. On OSX, this can be a side effect of the new System Integrity Protection stuff in Mojave. See http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/ for details. (Though it does sound like you did this already... Meanwhile, as @eftshift0 notes, it's not a good idea to try to `git init` your home directory.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what happened is that when you typed the `cd` command, you left a space in between the tilde and the rest of the path, so you changed back into your home directory (represented by the tilde). Then, when you tried to do a `git init`, you tried to initialize your home directory as a Git repository, and then ran into the fact that macOS restricts some programs (in your case, not Terminal, but maybe still Git) from accessing certain directories.

In the shell, the tilde is just a fancy way of spelling the environment variable `$HOME`, which points to your home directory (in this case, `/Users/savannahkeiffer`), so it should immediately precede the rest of the path without a space in between.

The best thing to do in this case is switch into your project directory and then initialize a repository there:

```
cd ~/Desktop/temporary_no_version_control # note the lack of space after the tilde
git init
```

If you didn't intend for your home directory to be a repository (i.e., you're not storing your dotfiles in a repository there), then you will probably also want to remove the `.git` directory from your home directory by running `rm -fr ~/.git`. Be careful when typing this, as `rm` removes data without prompting and an unfortunate space could result in all your data being deleted.

Comment: So I tried it again without the space and now it says:                                               
       'bash: cd: /Users/savannahkeiffer/Deskptop/no_version_control: No such file or 
       directory'                                                                                                                               but I double checked and that's where my file is located on my computer. Would you happen to know why it wouldn't register that my file is there? Is there something that I need to do in R to change the location of where files and repositories are saved?

Comment: I just figured it out! I created a new project and saved it to my documents instead of my desktop and it worked for some reason. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

[image: 1]

Hello this was an issue I had also but in Windows. It was a simple fix, user error. I hadn't used gitbash for awhile so I forgot the process with working in gitbash. First mistake I made was after opening gitbash I directly executed the git status command. That's when I got the "warning: could not open the directory" message. You need to using the cd (change directory) command and the dir (directory) command to navigate to the folder that has the files you want to "git add ." and "git commit -m". Once you get to that folder you will be able to use the "git status" command to see your changes then proceed as normal. I had to post this because it took me hours before I realized what I was doing wrong. No other stack post pointed this obvious user mistake. Hope it helps you.